# Connection in using TeamViewer : router or cable?

Tags: teamviewer

While using TeamViewer in local network (not via internet), the connection between the computer and the tablet/mobile is through router, etherent cable or just a USB cable? How to setup this connection? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Teamviewer Options > General > Network Settings > Incoming LAN connections

and set it to what you want, then you can connect via hostname or ip

[image]